Stellar Term Signer Help
I accidently added a token on the stellar term webiste and it created a signer for which I dont know the private key to. On stellar expert summary it reads 20/20/20 account is unlocked and 1w,10w,10w I do know the key for the last, my question is how can i remove the signer if possible, if not how can i move my funds? everytime i try to swap/send i need to approve the transaction but i dont have thee multi-sign in the lobstr vault, ive read something about set options on stellar laboratory but didnt really have enough info to do anything useful only general. is this a lost cause, thank you for any response. EDIT I WAS SCAMMED>

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
